# Fazer INNER JOIN em duas bases diferentes

Tags: mysql

Tenho 2 bancos de dados MySQL diferentes, consigo fazer uma consulta em uma base ou outra especificando qual a conexão que vou usar assim:

```
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $banco1);
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $banco2);
```

Agora surgiu um problema, preciso em uma mesma consulta fazer um INNER JOIN com tabelas de bancos diferentes, é possível? (algo nesse estilo)

```
$sql0 = "SELECT * FROM tabela1_banco1
INNER JOIN id ON tabela2_banco2.id = tabela1_banco1.id_usuario";
$result0 = mysql_query($sql0, $banco1, $banco2);
```

Comment: Dá erro, ou não apresenta nenhum valor?

Comment: Erro, ele nãoa ceita 2 bancos: mysql_query() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given

Comment: @caiocafardo, a resposta abaixo resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível; você só precisa referenciar os bancos a que as tabelas pertencem:

```
$sql0 = "SELECT * 
   FROM banco1.tabela
   INNER JOIN banco2.tabela ON banco2.tabela.id = banco1.tabela.id";
```

Comment: Nãoe ntendi o funcionamento, como ficaria o $result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $banco2);?